# TimescaleDB: Is it possible to call 'create_hypertable' from Python?

Tags: python-3.x, timescaledb

I want to create TimescaleDB tables in Postgres on the fly as I'm dealing with data sources that change (financial feeds, so could be 100, could be 1000) over time and I want one table per data source.

I can create the tables no problem from Python, but when I call `SELECT create_hypertable(test_table1, time)` it throws an error. The same query seems to work fine when executed from pSQL of course, so it looks like the timescale API isn't available via psycopg2 perhaps?

### Environment:

- Python 3.6.4
- psycopg2-binary-2.7.4 (installed with the flag: --no-binary :all:)
- Postgres: 10.3
- Timescaledb: 0.8.0-2
- MacOS: 10.13.3

### Test Code:

```
db.query("CREATE TABLE test_table1 (time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, name CHAR(100) NOT NULL")
db.query("SELECT create_hypertable('test_table1', 'time')")
```

### Error:

> 2018-03-05 11:45:36,901 [MainThread  ] [ERROR]  function create_hypertable(unknown, unknown) does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT create_hypertable('temp_table1', 'time')
>   . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ^
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Does anyone know if there currently anyway to making this work? Have I missed something simple? Or is there another service that can replace timescale functionality that supports being dynamically created?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That output implies that you haven't installed the `TimescaleDB` extension on the database you're running `create_hypertable` on. Make sure you run:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;
```

on your database before running `create_hypertable`. To ensure the extension has been created, run the following query:

```
select * from pg_extension;
```

`psycopg` shouldn't have any effect on this as the `.query()` call appears to just be executing the raw SQL you pass it. Make sure your `psycopg` client is connected to the same database as the one you initially installed the `TimescaleDB` extension on.

Comment: Ahhhhhh! So this is the solution: I had run `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;` on the database when I created it following the installation steps - but because I have a reset script that drops all the tables and creates them again - I have to run `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;` again to connect the extension again. So when I had it working in pSQL, it was before I ran the reset script and of course, when I tried from Python, it was after.

Comment: So this knocks out the connection: `self.query("DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE", True)` | `self.query("CREATE SCHEMA public", True)` | `self.query("GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO postgres", True)`| `self.query("GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO public", True)`. Thanks very much for you help, much appreciated!

Comment: I tried above described method but still getting the same error. SELECT create_hypertable('conditions', 'time');
ERROR:  function create_hypertable(unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT create_hypertable('conditions', 'time');
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on Postgres: 12, it's resolved in Postgres: 13 by adding the parameter `if_not_exists`:

```sql
SELECT create_hypertable('table_name', 'time', if_not_exists => TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try casting your inputs it looks like it could be an issue with the way inputs are being treated.So something like `SELECT create_hypertable('test_table1'::regclass, 'time'::name);` might work better.

Answer (score 1):

If U're sure that extension is loaded simply do:

```
db.query("SELECT public.create_hypertable('test_table1', 'time')")
```

in my case i have sheme "my_scheme" (not public one) and create_hypertable exists for scheme public only

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation [Here](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/getting-started/setup), we have to "Extend the database with TimescaleDB", and so, before converting the table to "hypertable", we must execute the below command, to extend.

> CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;