# Timescaledb extension not enabled intermittently

Tags: docker, timescaledb

I am using `timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg11` docker image to run timescale in my local.
While testing, I tried running it multiple times. Once while trying to creat a `hyper_table`, I got the below error,

> function create_hypertable(unknown, unknown, migrate_data => boolean) does not exist

As troubleshooting, I got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49111932/2046462), which suggested checking the *pg extensions*. So on the run when I got error, I didn't have `timescaledb` in the result of `select * from pg_extension;`. Whereas, in successful cases, I had the `timescaledb` extension.

I am unable to reproduce the error case again. But any idea why the issue happened randomly?

***PS:*** I used the same docker run command to run the container everytime.

Comment: I have the same issue, but do not know why and how this happening.

Comment: I am not sure 'why'. But the linked answer solved the problem then.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. I fixed it by using this docker-compose file

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  postgres:
    image: timescale/timescaledb-postgis
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_DB: tutorial
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
```