# TimescaleDB: Image does not recognize created hypertables

Tags: django, postgresql, timescaledb

I am running a django app with timescaledb as local DB image. It was working until recently (maybe 2 days ago). Now I get the following error:

```
 ERROR:  function create_hypertable(unknown, unknown, chunk_time_interval => interval) does not exist at character 8
 HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answers to other questions (e.g: [TimescaleDB: Is it possible to call 'create_hypertable' from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101709)) regarding this topic suggest to install the timescaledb extension. But I am running the `timescaledb-ha` image which comes with the extension included (https://hub.docker.com/r/timescaledev/timescaledb-ha).

I also tried to create the hypertables with `if_not_exists => TRUE` as suggested here: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/189.

I assume there is a bug in the image since it was updated 2 days ago and before it was working. Parts of my dockerfile:

```
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_postgis
    image: timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg14
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
```

Can somebody help? Would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: show the SQL that is causing the error